# How to parse/extract nested JSON data with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing, nested-lists

I am currently trying to extract product data from a JSON feed that contains nested data.

The nested structure is looking as follows: http://live.icecat.biz/api/?shopname=openIcecat-live&lang=en&content=featuregroups&icecat_id=1334921

I basically want to extract basic datasheet information for products in the database. Each product has different feature categories at the "top-level" and varying features below that in a nested structure.

My code looks like this so far:

```
import requests
url2 = 'http://live.icecat.biz/api/?shopname=openIcecat-live&lang=de&content=featuregroups&icecat_id=1334921'

content = requests.get(url).content

j = json.loads(content)    

for each in j['data']['FeaturesGroups']:
    print each ['FeatureGroup']['Name']['Value']
```

It works fine and prints the headlines of each feature category. But I am unable to parse the individual features. How can I do this ?

My attempt was to use a second loop to iterate over j['data']['FeaturesGroups']['Features'] (see below) but no success :/

```
for each in j['data']['FeaturesGroups']:
    for each in ['Features']:
        print ['Feature']['ID']
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `for each in ['Features']` -> `for each2 in each['Features']` / `print ['Feature']['ID']` -> `print(each2['ID'])`.

Comment: I basically want to extract every single feature per product from the JSON data. And I can't manage to get the data below the "FeatureGroup".  But I need the data at: data > FeaturesGroups > 0 > FeatureGroup > Features > Feature > Name > Value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
url2 = 'http://live.icecat.biz/api/?shopname=openIcecat-live&lang=de&content=featuregroups&icecat_id=1334921'

content = requests.get(url2).content

j = json.loads(content)

for each in j['data']['FeaturesGroups']:
    print each['FeatureGroup']['Name']['Value']
    for i in each["Features"]:
        print i["ID"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://live.icecat.biz/api/?shopname=openIcecat-live&lang=de&content=featuregroups&icecat_id=1334921'

content = requests.get(url).content

j = json.loads(content)    

def find_all(item, level):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k in item:
            print k
            find_all(item[k],level+1)
    else:
        print ' '*level ,item

for each in j['data']['FeaturesGroups']:
    find_all(each['FeatureGroup'], 0)


ID
  3
Name
Language
   DE
ID
   437975
Value
   Speicher
ID
  28
Name
Language
   DE
ID
   437998
Value
   Betriebsbedingungen
ID
  146
Name
Language
   DE
ID
   624349
Value
   Weitere Spezifikationen
```